# What caused USER to have "root" as OWNER and GROUP instead of the user's name? How do I change it?

Tags: permissions, users, root, home

/home (machine 1)

```
 PERMISSION |  OCTAL | OWNER          GROUP          NAME
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           .
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           ..
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | dietpi         dietpi         dietpi
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           joe
```

/home (machine 2)

```
 PERMISSION |  OCTAL | OWNER          GROUP          NAME
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           .
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           ..
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | dietpi         dietpi         dietpi
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | joe            joe            joe
```

I have two dietpi machines setup exactly the same for two USERs except for glitch shown.

1. What action might have caused `joe` to have `root` OWNER GROUP on machine 1?
2. How do I change OWNER GROUP to `joe` on machine 1? Should I change it?

Comment: Did you set up the machines separately, or transfer the image across from M2 to M1? Most likely cause is that you missed the requirement to give the new user `joe` ownership of his own home directory. Root user in `/home` should just need `chown joe:joe joe`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thank you I made the change as directed. M1 existed prior to the independent setup of M2. I don't recall now but I might have tried to setup the M1 USER from a backup of a prior dietpi version on USB stick.